# .htaccess redirect - should this work?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /resources/(.*) /community//$1
```

To redirect these sorts of URL's:

```
http://www.domain.com/resources/view/123
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/community/view/123
```

and

```
http://www.domain.com/resources/all/
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/community/all/
```

Given the rule above, should it do what i need it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work just fine (but I would still remove double slash `//` in target URL part -- single slash is enough).

In any case -- you can make it a bit simpler (no need for relatively expensive regex at all for such simple redirect). Simple `Redirect` instead of `RedirectMatch` will do the same job:

```
Redirect 301 /resources/ /community/
```